# GPUImageMovieWriter not recording audio

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I saw a previous thread had the same issue but I wanted to see if there are any ideas. I have an app where I take a sequence of photos then an option to record a message pops up. I have my exposure locked but when I go to record a video it unlocks and it doesn't go back to the original state when I am done recording. I moved

```
self.stillCamera.audioEncodingTarget = self.movieWriter;
```

to

```
viewDidLoad
```

like a previous thread said to do. This fixed the exposure issue but now there is no audio. I am stumped.

Here's some of the code.

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
takephotocolor.hidden = YES;
takephotobw.hidden = YES;
self.stillCamera.audioEncodingTarget = self.movieWriter;

}

(IBAction)StartButtonPressed:(id)sender {
if(!self.transform){

self.transform = [[GPUImageTransformFilter alloc] init];
CATransform3D perspectiveTransform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DMakeRotation(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                                        -1, 1, 1);
[self.transform setTransform3D:perspectiveTransform];
}

[self.filter addTarget:self.transform];

self.pathToMovie = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/movie.mov"];
unlink([self.pathToMovie UTF8String]);
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.pathToMovie];
self.movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL        size:CGSizeMake(1024.0, 768.0)];


[self.transform addTarget:self.movieWriter];
 [self.movieWriter startRecording];

btnStart.hidden = YES;
btnStop.hidden = NO;
NSLog(@"START RECORDING");
}

(IBAction)StopButtonPressed:(id)sender {
self.stillCamera.audioEncodingTarget = nil;
[self.movieWriter finishRecording];

[self.filter removeTarget:self.transform];
[self.transform removeAllTargets];
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.pathToMovie, self, nil, nil);

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(goVideo) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `self.stillCamera.audioEncodingTarget = nil;` after the call to `[self.movieWriter finishRecording];` That's how I have it set up at least.